# Azure function file not found

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-4.8

I created an Azure function which uses a packages that needs a properties file in order to work. From the way they implemented this I need to pass the property file location to the package.

```cs
ConfigFactory.setConfigLocation("SomeFolder/AnotherFolder/connector.properties");
```

When I run this locally this works just fine and everything works as intended. However when I publish it on Azure it tells me the file url is invalid,

> [Error] Invalid url to location ]SomeFolder/AnotherFolder/connector.properties[ errorMessage :no protocol: SomeFolder/AnotherFolder/connector.properties file

Am I missing something? How come this doesn't just work on Azure?

Comment: question - do you see the file deployed at Azure. You can validate using Kudu in Azure portal. If yes, then try to use the absolute path instead of relative path. Try finding the required root path using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` and using that combine with the current relative path should give the absolute path of the `connector.properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to a file in an azure function you have 2 options.

Using **Execution Context** :

```
[FunctionName("MyNewHTTPAzureFunction")]

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string name = req.Query["name"];
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response." : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
    
    //This is how you can access the curent Directory with the help of context.FunctionAppDirectory
    
    string localFile = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Data", "Your_file_with_extension");   
    string readLocalFile = File.ReadAllText(localFile);
    
    ...... // your business needs
    
    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

Use **Path.GetDirectoryName** :

To access the directory of the Azure Function if you don’t have access to the **ExecutionContext**.

You can read the local file in your **Startup class** like below.

```
var getPath= Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var rootpath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(binpath, ".."));

///Read the file

File.ReadAllText(rootpath + "/path/to/filename_with_extension");
```

### **Azure Function Access To The Path Is Denied**

To avoid the Access Denied error in Azure functions, You Always try to keep your files in the `D:\home\site\wwwroot` **(root Directory)**  directory that is exactly where exactly the Azure Function resides.

Refer for more information [here](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-access-azure-functions-wwwroot-folder/) & Doc for  [Binding Expression pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns)

Comment: YES!!! that seems to be working. Thank you so much for putting all this effort in answering my question and giving me context for why it was not working. You helped me a lot!